# Color based on value of matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

im kind anew to Matlab/octave but i am used to work with R. So what i would like to do is the following. I want to plot my t.test result (y value) vs the the t.test difference (x value). Quite simple i do get this data with R but i would like to plot with Matlab. The thing is that the color of the dots should change based on a value  in a certain column. So basically it is the p value. So i got three column with y x and p value.

what i am missing is the ifelse function from R.

So maybe:

```
if [:,3]<0.05
     a='red';
elseif [:,3]<0.01
      a='green';
else 
   a=  black;
end
```

it should be easier.

Comment: matlab has an `elseif` function rather than ifelse. I have updated the post to match your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have an array of n-by-3, with columns [difference,result,p-value] called `data`. You can then plot `data` like this:

```
figure,hold on
idxK = data(:,3) > 0.05;
plot(data(idxK,1),data(idxK,2),'k')
idxG = data(:,3) < 0.01;
plot(data(idxG,1),data(idxG,2),'g')
plot(data(~(idxG|idxK),1),data(~(idxG|idxK),2),'r')
```

Alternatively, you can use `scatter`

```
colorIdx = data(:,3)>0.05 + data(:,3)>0.01 + 1;
figure 
scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2),[],colorIdx)
colormap([0 1 0;1 0 0;0 0 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking for, but if you set up the numbers in advance in a square matrix, then try using [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

for example, try doing `imagesc(rand(5));`. in this case, `rand(5)` makes a 5x5 matrix of random numbers.

Hope this helps.